# stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, installation, environment-variables, anaconda

I'm trying to install required dependencies for Intel's DC to edge course. While creating the environment by

```
C:\Geth\DC to Edge Course\Notebooks>conda env create -f environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: C:\Users\Palash\Anaconda3\envs\Taco\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
```

but this didn't worked, So I did a workaround and created an environment ' Intel_dc2edge' and then tried updating it with following code and results are -

```
  (Intel_dc2edge) C:\Geth\DC to Edge Course\Notebooks>conda env update --prefix ./env --file environment.yml
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
ERROR conda.core.link:_execute(700): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0'.
Rolling back transaction: done

LinkError: post-link script failed for package defaults::qt-5.9.7-vc14h73c81de_0
location of failed script: C:\Geth\DC to Edge Course\Notebooks\env\Scripts\.qt-post-link.bat
==> script messages <==
<None>
==> script output <==
stdout:         1 file(s) copied.

stderr: 'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'chcp' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

return code: 1

()
```

I think it clearly is a problem of path, have looked up for chcp.com file and it's present in windows system32.

[this is list of environment variables in my system](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLpff.jpg)

I did this by recommendation from JosefZ

[this was the recommendation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwOhs.jpg)

Comment: Open `cmd.exe` and run `echo [%path:;=]&echo.[%]`  to ensure that there  are not some unwanted trailing  spaces or other _invisible_ characters.

Comment: did that and updated In the question, I think that's fine.

Comment: `where chcp` should show `C:\Windows\System32\chcp.com` even if run from _any_ directory different from `C:\Windows\System32`. Try `echo [%path:;=]&echo.[%]` as well as `where chcp` from your initial environment _without_ previous invoking `cmd.exe`. Try it in an  open _pure_ `cmd.exe` (open from Windows start menu). Moreover, check at least your `.qt-post-link.bat` script if there are some incorrect `path` manipulations. Hint: `findstr /I /S "set..*path\=" "C:\Users\Palash\Anaconda3\envs\Taco\Scripts\*.bat"`